# include файла другого пользователя

Tags: php

Возможно ли как-то подключить файл в `/var/www/user1` из `/var/www/user2`? Или это зависит от настроек сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от настроек сервера, вы можете на уровне виртуального хоста `user1` определить директиву

```
open_basedir = /var/www/user1
```

а на уровне виртуального хоста пользователя `user2` определить директиву

```
open_basedir = /var/www/user2
```

Тогда PHP-скрипты из первого хоста, не смогут выполняться выше `/var/www/user1`, а скрипты из второго, выше `/var/www/user2`. Если сервер работает под управлением **Apache**, значение `open_basedir` можно установить при помощи директивы `php_admin_value`. Если вы имеете дело с PHP-FPM, то можно под каждого пользователя выделить свой пул и управлять директивами конфигурационного файла пула.

Если это ваш собственный сервер, вы можете не изолировать пользователей и тогда скрипты из одного проекта смогут обращаться к файлам другого.